# Visibility Trigger not firing for tags

Tags: angularjs, angular, google-tag-manager

Any tips why element visibility triggers could not work? I have angular modules generating custom tags like `<opinions>` or `<basic-news>` etc. (some of them fire the trigger, some of them not)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this question for Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: Could you please provide further details about the inspected tags, and the trigger settings? E.g., have you enabled DOM inspection in tag manager, to support tracking of dynamically created elements?